# Send data between two android devices over internet without using any intermediate server

Tags: android, api, sockets, tcp

I am working on an android application, in this I need to transfer some data between two android devices over internet connection without using any intermediate server. Some sugession provided for this task as follows :

1. [Using socket programming](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

   If I use this approach, there is possibility of changing IP address when device reconnect to network.
2. [using sip2peer API](https://code.google.com/p/sip2peer/)

   It seems to be a good option, but documents of this API are not so clear, I am not able to understand and run its android example, if someone having experience with that API , please provide me some hint of using this in android, I am also not getting that does we need to maintain a server for using this API or not.

Please provide me some hint, how can I achieve this task.

Comment: to use sip2peer api you also need intermediate server which is call sip server.

Comment: @ Biraj Zalavadia ... thanks for your reply, can you please tell me how can I configure it at  my local pc for testing purpose, means how can I configure sip2peer on my local pc and android device for testing.

Comment: I don't have worked on sip but you can start with here http://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-up-sip-server-windows